# Getting Map value from JAXB Response Object

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap-client, spring-ws

I am using Spring WS Template to call a JAX-WS web service. The response would like as follows. Here I need get the value of key2 from the response object how do I need to do that ? Here I am using JAXB client.

```
<MyResponse>
        <return>
            <map>
               <key>key1</key>
               <value>value1</value>
            </map>
            <map>
               <key>key2</key>
               <value>value2</value>
            </map>
            <map>
               <key>key3</key>
               <value>value3</value>
            </map>
            <param1></param1>
            <param2></param2>
            <param3></param3>
            ......
            ......
        </return>
    </MyResponse>
```

The following code would return MapWrapper and I have no idea how to get the key from the returned MapWrapper

```
myResponse.getReturn();// returns MapWrapper
```

Comment: Have you tried myResponse.getReturn().getMap()?

Comment: You are correct, this is pretty simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MapWrapper don't have specific methods, but it could simply be treated as a Map.

```
      List<MapElement> elements = conversationResponse.getReturn().getMap();

      for (MapElement mapElement : elements) {

        if (mapElement.getKey() != null
            && mapElement.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("key2")) {

          val = mapElement.getValue();
          break;
        }

      }
```